# Use JLine to Complete Multiple Commands on One Line

Tags: java, jline

I was wondering how I could implement an `ArgumentCompleter` such that if I complete a full and valid command, then it would begin tab completing for a new command.

I would have assumed it could be constructed doing something like this:

```
final ConsoleReader consoleReader = new ConsoleReader()

final ArgumentCompleter cyclicalArgument = new ArgumentCompleter();
cyclicalArgument.getCompleters().addAll(Arrays.asList(
        new StringsCompleter("foo"), 
        new StringsCompleter("bar"), 
        cyclicalArgument));

consoleReader.addCompleter(cyclicalArgument);
consoleReader.readLine();
```

However right now this stops working after tab completeing the first `foo bar`

Is anyone familiar enough with the library to tell me how I would go about implementing this? Or is there a known way to do this that I am missing? Also this is using JLine2.

Answer (score 5):

That was quite a task :-)

It is handled by the completer you are using. The `complete()` method of the completer has to use for the search only what comes after the last blank.

If you look for example at the `FileNameCompleter` of the library: this is not done at all, so you will find no completion, because the completer searches for `<input1> <input2>` and not only for `<input2>` :-)

You will have to do your own implementation of a completer that is able to find input2.

Additionally the `CompletionHandler` has to append what you found to what you already typed.

Here is a basic implementation changing the default `FileNameCompleter`:

```
  protected int matchFiles(final String buffer, final String translated, final File[] files,
         final List<CharSequence> candidates) {
      // THIS IS NEW
      String[] allWords = translated.split(" ");
      String lastWord = allWords[allWords.length - 1];
      // the lastWord is used when searching the files now
      // ---

      if (files == null) {
         return -1;
      }

      int matches = 0;

      // first pass: just count the matches
      for (File file : files) {
         if (file.getAbsolutePath().startsWith(lastWord)) {
            matches++;
         }
      }
      for (File file : files) {
         if (file.getAbsolutePath().startsWith(lastWord)) {
            CharSequence name = file.getName() + (matches == 1 && file.isDirectory() ? this.separator() : " ");
            candidates.add(this.render(file, name).toString());
         }
      }

      final int index = buffer.lastIndexOf(this.separator());

      return index + this.separator().length();
   }
```

And here the `complete()`-Method of the `CompletionHandler` changing the default `CandidateListCompletionHandler`:

```
  @Override
   public boolean complete(final ConsoleReader reader, final List<CharSequence> candidates, final int pos)
         throws IOException {
      CursorBuffer buf = reader.getCursorBuffer();

      // THIS IS NEW
      String[] allWords = buf.toString().split(" ");
      String firstWords = "";
      if (allWords.length > 1) {
         for (int i = 0; i < allWords.length - 1; i++) {
            firstWords += allWords[i] + " ";
         }
      }
      //-----

      // if there is only one completion, then fill in the buffer
      if (candidates.size() == 1) {
         String value = Ansi.stripAnsi(candidates.get(0).toString());

         if (buf.cursor == buf.buffer.length() && this.printSpaceAfterFullCompletion && !value.endsWith(" ")) {
            value += " ";
         }

         // fail if the only candidate is the same as the current buffer
         if (value.equals(buf.toString())) {
            return false;
         }

         CandidateListCompletionHandler.setBuffer(reader, firstWords + " " + value, pos);

         return true;
      } else if (candidates.size() > 1) {
         String value = this.getUnambiguousCompletions(candidates);
         CandidateListCompletionHandler.setBuffer(reader, value, pos);
      }

      CandidateListCompletionHandler.printCandidates(reader, candidates);

      // redraw the current console buffer
      reader.drawLine();

      return true;
   }
```

Comment: Hmm,. so this is gonna take some larger changes than I thought. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: At least it seems you cannot activate it by some config. But you can make a standard implementation and inherit it for your next classes.